# NetBeans Highlighting Issue in HTML

Tags: html, netbeans, highlight

I'm using NetBeans 12 and I hate the fact that it highlights all instances of classnames in HTML and leaves them highlighted with no apparent way to remove the highlighting until another classname/id is selected.

[image]

I have searched for answers, and a common one is to use Tools > Options > Editor > Highlighting and deselect "mark occurrences of symbol under carat." I think that is for a different problem though, and for some reason the only language in the dropdown is PHP, so I can't uncheck this for HTML anyway.

Please tell me how I can stop this annoying behaviour, or at least use a keyboard shortcut to remove the highlighting. I would have though something like ESC would be set up to do this as default, but no...

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors

There you will see a drop-down list of different style profiles. In my case, I have "FlatLaf Light" selected. Yours may be different, but that should not matter.

Choose the "Syntax" sub-menu.

In the "language" list choose "HTML"

In the "Category" list, scroll down to "CSS embedded in HTML" and then select it.

Change the "Background" color to "Inherited".

Hit "Apply" to save your changes.

In my case, this looks as follows:

Before the change:

[image]

After the change:

[image]

---

This changes the (very specific) highlighting issue shown in your question's screenshot. But you may want to make a similar change in other places... For example, you can see the opening and closing (matching) `<ul>` tags are highlighted (which I find useful).

So, you can also take a look at other languages - and even the "All Languages" option for a broader range of places where similar changes can be made (e.g "Mark Occurrences"). But I have not investigated these in any detail.

---

Final notes - all subjective and based on personal preferences...

You may choose to keep the highlighting feature, but to use a less intrusive color, of course, instead of completely removing it.

I am using NetBeans 15 - so that may affect which overall look and feel themes you have available, also. But a different theme (retaining the highlighting) may also be another option.